# Does this "algebraic" method for the application of the constructive proof of the classification of closed & compact surfaces have any use?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, compact-manifolds

In a typical (at least from what I have seen) geometric topology course, when the classification of closed & compact surfaces is introduced, what has been done first is to find equivalent surfaces by cutting and gluing operations, as it can be seen in [2].

Later in the course, as I have introduced, to classify surfaces, one uses tools like euler characteristic, homology and homotopy groups, and orient ability. However, while we were using only cutting and gluing operations, I have noticed that with only 3 simple rules, one can achieve the same result as with the cutting and gluing, only in this case we only manipulate the names of the edges given to them. I have explained the whole methodology in this [2 page long paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324720882_An_algebraic_method_for_the_application_of_the_constructive_proof_of_classification_theorem_for_closed_and_connected_surfaces).

Although I did not put the method into a solid framework, this method helped me a lot while taking the course: whenever it is asked to find the type of a given surface, I was able to give the correct answer with a high confidence, since with this method, it is much more clear what I was doing compared to draw each cut and glue one by one.Plus, it is a much quicker method.

[2] Kinsey, Topology of Surfaces, p85, Lemma 4.15

---

### Question:

First of all, is this an original work ? or I have re-discovered something, or part of something, that has already been established ?

Secondly, if we were to put this method into a formal ground (assuming there is no problem with the validity of the method), how could we do that ? What do we exactly need ?

(Optional)Thirdly, do you think this method is useful in any sense ?

---

**Just a side note:**

This was the first article (-ish) paper that I have ever tried to write, so I'm more than happy to see any kind of feedback about the paper, or its methodology.

Comment: You might take a look at Chapter 6 of my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_, where I carry out a proof along lines very similar to what you're suggesting.

Comment: By the way, the algebraic invariants (Euler characteristic; homology and homotopy groups; orientability) are still necessary for a complete theory, no matter what rules you can craft to carry out the cut-and-paste operations. While cut and paste operations can prove *existence* of a homeomorphism between two surfaces (when one exists), algebraic invariants are needed to prove *nonexistence* of a homeomorphism between two surfaces (when none exists).

Comment: @JackLee I checked your book (version 2000), chapter 6, but couldn't find anything like that. Is there any chance that you can point me to that specific proof ?